# Are these reasonings about tides correct?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, earth

This is a picture of the "M2 tidal constituent":

[image: https://www.google.ca/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CAcQjRxqFQoTCJL955jj0cgCFYQ1PgodipcOcA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FTide&psig=AFQjCNFzviJsrhalCGigLbctZBjuiUwTuA&ust=1445455419272369]

The nodes corresponds to fixed points, for which the moon has no influence on the altitude.

**1. Static VS Dynamic problem?** I was first wondering if tide is a dynamic or a quasi-static problem. The question is whether the vertical inertial forces $\rho\ddot z$ can be neglected compared to the Moon volumic attraction. Typically, $z(t)$ is a sine of half-amplitude two meters and period 12 hours (40e3 seconds) so the $\ddot z$ is about $2\omega^2\approx 5\times 10^{-8}$m/s^2. The Moon attraction is $m_\text{Moon}G/d^2\approx 3\times10^{-5}$m/s^2. So the inertial forces are very small compared to the Moon attraction. I feel something is wrong about this, is there an obvious reasoning mistake?

**2. Tides VS Sloshing modes?** In solid dynamics, in a linear framework, the response to a system can be decomposed as a sum of modes. My first thought was that, similarly, the motion of the ocean could be decomposed as a sum of sloshing modes under the action of the Moon (and the Sun too), as for example if you walk with a bowl full of milk. However, from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tide:

> Galileo Galilei in his 1632 Dialogue Concerning the Two Chief World
> Systems, whose working title was Dialogue on the Tides, gave an
> explanation of the tides. The resulting theory, however, **was incorrect
> as he attributed the tides to the sloshing of water** caused by the
> Earth's movement around the sun.

Why is this intuition wrong?

Comment: I don't know if you have access to this article, but if so this will be of use: http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/pdf/10.1146/annurev.fl.02.010170.001225

Comment: @NickP I do have access, I'll have a look, thank you.

Comment: Npte "by the earths movement around the sun" you are proposing "the action of the Moon and sun" as the originators. It is inevitable that fluid dynamics has to be used, the originating impulses have to be correct

Comment: @annav I'm not sure what you mean; is it that I am not considering the rotation of the Earth around the centre of mass of the system Moon-Earth?